# header height with fluid layouts

Tags: html, css, height, responsive-design, fluid-layout

#### Intro

I'm doing a website with fluid layouts (all container widths are expressed in %) for fitting all resolutions. It is ok and it looks nice in browser with small resolution, wide imac screen, tablet and mobile.

#### The layout

it has some coloumns and it is thoughts for a 1200px page. the layout is like this one:

[image]

#### The problem

But I have a problem with the header height. For now it is fixed:

```
#title {
    padding-top: 135px;
}
```

I'd like the header height change in base of the resolution but i don't know how to fix it.

If i use percentage for the height it is not clear on how it is calculated.. i should use `html, body { height: 100%; }` but what if the content is different from one page to another? and if the content overflow the viewport?

Comment: Did you tried percentage for your header.

Comment: no i haven't tried because it is not clear for me on how i have to scale the dimension. if the content of the column olverflow the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with some javascript and jquery:

```
    function resizeTitle() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var h = width;
        $("header").css("height", h/8+"px");
        $("header #title").css("padding-top", h/14+"px");
    }
    $(window).resize(resizeTitle);
    resizeTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly why the % values does not work with height or other vertical properties.

What I do is to use media queries.

ex:

```
#title {
padding-top: 135px;
}
@media screen and (max-width=600px)
    #title {
    padding-top: 100px
    }
}
```

And so on with every screen size.

You can use some tool like webdeveloper toolbar to see how it display in several screen resolutions

Comment: no i haven't tried the % on the height because it is not clear for me on how i have to scale it. if the content of the column olverflow the viewport? what do i have to consider the 100% ?